# "Phantom" touches on appliance's capacitive buttons. A serious problem?

Tags: safety, electric-machine, appliances

We have two electronic devices that operate well by themselves.

Device 1 has touch (I assume capacitive) buttons.

If device 1 and 2 are turned on they are fine. But if device 2's motor is engaged, device 1 will start registering touches on its buttons.

We would like to know if this is a harmless problem, or if it indicates a more serious issue with either device, or with our electrical wiring.

Devices:

1. Pressure cooker
   [image]
2. Exercise machine
   [image]

I should mention that we had another odd problem in the past whereby our washing machine's metal drum would become energized if its plug was inserted upside-down, flipping the poles of the plug (with an accidentally flipped plug adapter).

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather want an electrician check your installation..

Comment: How far are the devices physically separated?

Comment: Approx. 2 metres (7 ft).

Comment: You have ghosts, call the ghost busters

Comment: You mentioned a plug adapter and being able to flip the plug around, if that is possible to do and your original plug was polarized or had a ground that isn't passed through, then the adapter is a death trap and should be burned with fire. Do the appliances have three prong plugs and you are not connecting the ground pin? As in, exactly what is the adapter adapting and are you using ones on any other appliances?

Answer (score 2):

It means that the exercise machine wasn't designed for good conducted noise immunity.  There are lots of crappy designs out there.

The first device is probably putting noise onto the power line, which confuses the second device to where it thinks buttons got touched.

The signal to noise ratio of capacitive sense buttons is pretty small to begin with.  Of course there are ways to mitigate this, but the designers would first have to care, then know what they are doing.

Whether this is a problem only you can say.  We have no way of knowing how important it is to you that the second device doesn't start doing random things when the first device is in use.

As for the washing machine, don't do that.  The plug was apparently polarized for a reason.  I can't imagine why you'd deliberately flip the plug, but next time give the Darwin Awards people a heads up so they can get a trophy ready.

Comment: Thank you - the plug was not flipped on purpose, it was accidental, and certainly not repeated!

Comment: On the side note of the washing machine - would you consider it normal / acceptable for an appliance chassis to become energised in the case of accidental plug flipping?

Comment: Can I ask if there is a way to mitigate the line noise caused by appliance 1?

Comment: @sky: I don't consider it normal for a plug to be flipped.  You were clearly doing something you weren't supposed to.  Personally, I would want the drum to be tied to ground, not either of the two power leads.

Comment: @sky: A line filter may help.

Comment: A plug should not _be_ flippable, polarized plugs cannot be physically inserted in unpolarized sockets at all or polarized ones inserted upside down.